# Formula for computed column based on others column

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this

```
Formular  | A  | B  | C | ....
----------------------------------------
(A + B)   | 5  | 10 | 8 | ....
(B + C)   | 8  | 5  | 1 | ....
(A - Y)   | 10 | 0  | 9 | ....
(A + Z)   | 2  | 0  | 0 | ....
```

How can i select to get new table like below

```
Formular  | A  | B  | C | ....| ToTal
----------------------------------------
(A + B)   | 5  | 10 | 8 | ....| 15
(B + C)   | 8  | 5  | 1 | ....| 6
(A - C)   | 10 | 0  | 9 | ....| 1
(A + Z)   | 10 | 0  | 9 | ....| ...
```

The `...` mean it can have many column and very dynamic

Thanks you very much!

Comment: You really don't want to do this. It requires dynamic sql and trying to do this in a computed column is a nightmare. It will prove to become incredibly challenging and highly likely to get things wrong.

Comment: Thanks Sean but it's the customer's requirement , Formula column can be change to store in difference table if we want. Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: You would be much better off storing the result when you save the data. This would mean calculating it outside of t-sql. Doing this kind of thing t-sql is painful and highly prone to error. Think about things like division. How do you prevent a 0 being entered into the divisor column? The only way you can do this in t-sql is with dynamic sql.

Comment: You need to use a function to for `Total` column. In that function get Id of current row (to access the row) and 2 operands and one operator. You should calculate the formula by dynamicall using raw query execution.

Comment: @Trada, can't you use a view instead of adding computed column?

Comment: @SiyavashHamdi the OP can't use a function here because it will require dynamic which is not allowed in a function.

Comment: And dynamic SQL is obviously a security risk as you are basically agreeing to `exec` Unknown code supplied in the formula column.

Comment: @FLICKER this will require dynamic sql to calculate which is not allowed in a view.

Comment: @SeanLange, no need to dynamic sql, using CASE with all possible combination of formula can do that.

Comment: I'm working with reporting service and this report is a bit challenge :( . I've tried to use dynamic sql but still not have any good solution yet. Formula may be not just (A + B) , it can be (A + B - F + Z - K) / G

Comment: I think there is no way other than dynamic sql.

Comment: Yes , I also think that , but still not find the way to write

Comment: Explain to me how any one table can have a dynamic number of columns?   I'd really like to hear this.  If you're working with reporting services, why don't you handle this in the SSRS Tablix?

Comment: Instead of using dynamic SQL, could you use formula in the report engine instead? A best pratice I use is to try to return the data to the report with minimal modification and let the report engine handle calculation and data computing.

Comment: Is there a max value A,B,C or ... can be? If there is a max value, building up a cartesian table (combinations of possible matches) would be efficient, and safer.

Comment: @Tab Alleman in SQL we have PIVOT function to convert row to column , so the column can be very dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have a primary key column in your table, skip the steps where I have added a row_number to rows and use your primary key column instead the rest should be the same.

### Test Data

```
CREATE TABLE Formulas (Formular VARCHAR(10), A INT  , B INT , C  INT)
GO
INSERT INTO Formulas VALUES 
('(A + B)'   , 5  , 10 , 8 ),
('(B + C)'   , 8  , 5  , 1 ),
('(A - C)'   , 10 , 0  , 9 ),
('(A + C)'   , 10 , 0  , 9 )
GO
```

### Create Temp Holding table

```
Select *
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rn
      ,0 AS Total
      INTO ##Temp
FROM Formulas 

ALTER TABLE ##Temp 
ADD [SQL] NVARCHAR(MAX)
GO
```

### Prepare SQL Statements

```
UPDATE ##Temp
SET [SQL] = 'Select @Total = ' + Formular + ' FROM ##Temp WHERE rn = @RowNumber'  
GO
```

### Execute SQL Statements and Populate Holding Table

```
Declare @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX) , @RowNumber INT, @Total INT

Declare Cur CURSOR FOR
SELECT rn , [SQL]
FROM ##Temp

OPEN Cur 

 FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @RowNumber , @Sql

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
    Exec sp_executesql @Sql
                      ,N'@RowNumber INT, @Total INT OUTPUT'
                      ,@RowNumber
                      ,@Total OUTPUT 

     Select   @Total , @Total
      UPDATE ##Temp SET Total = @Total WHERE rn = @RowNumber

    FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @RowNumber , @Sql
END

CLOSE Cur
DEALLOCATE Cur
```

### Final Results

```
Select Formular, A , B, C, Total 
from ##Temp

╔══════════╦════╦════╦═══╦═══════╗
║ Formular ║ A  ║ B  ║ C ║ Total ║
╠══════════╬════╬════╬═══╬═══════╣
║ (A + B)  ║  5 ║ 10 ║ 8 ║    15 ║
║ (B + C)  ║  8 ║  5 ║ 1 ║     6 ║
║ (A - C)  ║ 10 ║  0 ║ 9 ║     1 ║
║ (A + C)  ║ 10 ║  0 ║ 9 ║    19 ║
╚══════════╩════╩════╩═══╩═══════╝
```

Comment: Is this relevant to the question? OP is asking for computed column.

Comment: @FLICKER from what I understand it says in the question `How can i select to get new table like below` the OP is asking how to select not adding new columns, anyway if Adding new columns is required, the same login can be used to add new columns in the table, instead of using a select statement use `ALTER TABLE bla bla` and that would add the computed column, but I am pretty sure this is not what OP wants.

Comment: @M.Ali Thanks Ali , i understand your ideas , i'm also thinking about the loop , but how do you think about the performance ?

Comment: @Trada the performance will be terrible, because the way formulas are stored, SQL Server is not designed to handle situations like this.

Comment: @M.Ali Do you have any ideas to improve performance ? , i mean we can change the way we store formula.

Comment: @Trada a good starting point will be to stop storing formulas in the sql tables. Move them to a stored procedure etc.